# Move SQL Server project to big data?

Tags: sql-server, bigdata

I am not sure if this is correct StackExchange board to post this question, but I will give it a try.

We have a pretty extensive SQL Server backend in our ASP.NET application. It includes complex table structure, multiple views, store procedures and functions. Currently we're running it on in-house SQL Server 2005/2008 boxes. It's been in production for several years and runs pretty good.

But lately we have huge increase of data being added to the system, and the sheer volume of data started to slow down the system. Stored procedures take significantly more time to process data (we optimized them as far as we can go, added all necessary indexes to the tables etc.)

One suggestion was to move the project to "Big Data" services. Is it feasible? Can this be done with existing SQL Server project? What is involved? Will existing code/structures work or major redesign is required? Who would be the best provider for such move - Google, Microsoft, Amazon?

Thanks!

Comment: Moving to a big data platform isn't as easy as moving a SQL Server project to another platform.  If you want to scale out SQL Server, then Amazon, MS or others can help.  What type of data are you working with?

Comment: Data is diverse, numeric, text, blobs. The biggest tables have small number of columns, mixed INT and NVARCHAR data, but millions of rows of that

Comment: This will be a major redesign in my opinion.  You are looking at different structures and different ways of storing data.  What type of application is this?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET application. Data presented to user in form of grids, dashboards, charts etc. Behind the scenes SQL Server runs SPs, uses Views etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number one difference I think you'll face in trying to move from SQL Server to a Big Data service is the structure of the data.

Things like graph databases (Neo4j), batch processing (Hadoop), document databases (Mongo) ... all of them have very different data models.

The big move usually is going from normalized data to denormalized data. This can be pretty painful and a lot of work. For example, you'll have to find a way to consolidate 4-5 tables into one document.

If you wanted to really move forward migrating the entire database, I would do the following:

1. Research the data model you want to move to. Maybe something like MySQL will scale horizontally in a way that is cheaper that SQL Server? Maybe document databases will make development easier?
2. Once you know the new model, try different technologies in that space. So many big data databases are very young and I would recommend finding one with a good community (like Mongo).
3. Go table by table and decide how to model it in the new system/database.
4. Find a way to replace sprocs, views, functions with equivalent ideas in the new database. This can be pretty tough because those things just don't exist in a lot of big data databases. You'll end up pushing a lot of that functionality into the application layer. (Unless you go with MySQL).

What I might recommend instead is to stick with SQL Server. Some thoughts to help ease the burden on SQL Server:

1. Find the subset of data that is causing the most pain. Move that out to a big data system.
2. Introduce caching (if you don't already have it) at the application layer(s). Help relieve the read pressure.
3. Shard. You can always shard SQL Server which should help alleviate read problems/performance.
4. Write jobs to archive old data that isn't used. Move that data to another SQL Server instance that is "offline".